# Negotiating a verbal non written offer

Tags: negotiation

I received a call from HR with an offer that details salary packages and benefits. Should I wait for the written offer and contract to start negotiating or pick up the phone right now and call HR to say that 5% more will make me make a faster decision?

Comment: Pick up the phone right now.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Is there a better way to phrase it? Or is the 5% figure the problem?

Comment: @Brandin "I appreciate the offer and am extremely excited at the opportunity to work at your company. However, I was hoping for a salary closer to $XXX to make this decision much easier for myself/family. Let me know what you think, and thank you very much!". You can maybe add some justifications due to cost of living, market rate in that area, specialized skills you have, etc. but the hiring manager is probably already fairly aware of all that by the point they are extending an offer.

Comment: @Brandin: it sounds like a car salesman offering a great deal but only if you buy with cash today.

Answer (score 4):

You can negotiate over the phone. But do not talk about 'faster decision'. Be sure to ask them when you can get the written offer.